# Spring Security 5 Spring MVC Oauth 2 Password grant type not returning token with /oauth/token

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on a requirement trying to allow another trusted app (backend) to connect to our API using oauth2 password grant, but I am not able to get a token using /oauth/token.
Our application already has a basic form login authentication running with a login form.

Here is the original WebSecurityConfig that allows a user to login with a form. This has been working for a while.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("config")
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(2)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .headers().frameOptions().disable()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            //allow anyone to access the following with the pattern
            .antMatchers("/", "/static/**", "/ping", "/topic/**",  "/oauth/token" ).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/").permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .expiredUrl("/")
        .and()
            .invalidSessionUrl("/");
}

@Bean(name = "corsConfigurationSource")
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Cache-Control", "Authorization", "Content-Type", "content-type", "x-requested-with", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-auth-token", "x-app-id", "Origin", "Accept", "X-Requested-With", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}

@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
    return authProvider;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("md5");
}
}
```

And here is the new authorization server settings I added. I am just trying to get the simplest case running. So I am using in-memory for everything.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@ComponentScan ("config")
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory().withClient("client")
        .secret("clientpassword")
        .secret("{noop}secret")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
        .scopes("read", "write");
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.tokenStore( new InMemoryTokenStore())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.POST);
}
}
```

And this is another WebSecurityConfig I created, trying to separate the original one with the new one:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
@ComponentScan ("config")
@EnableWebSecurity (debug = true)
public class WebSecurityOauthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .csrf().disable();
    }
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
        .withUser("user").password("user").roles("ROLE");
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
   return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

And this is the version:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the request I send:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8081/oauth/token \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50OmNsaWVudHBhc3N3b3Jk' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 06a1108e-d620-4e01-b8f7-81eb7a57ae44' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F client_id=client \
  -F user=user \
  -F password=user \
  -F grant_type=password
```

No explicit error. This is the trace log from spring security. From what I see, the DaoAuthenticationProvider is not correctly registered. I was expecting using the in-memory user, but filter chain does not include it. I also tried auto-wiring userDetailsService, but result is the same

```
************************************************************

Request received for POST '/oauth/token':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@47616c04

servletPath:/oauth/token
pathInfo:null
headers: 
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------127172580218970013444831
authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50OmNsaWVudHBhc3N3b3Jk
cache-control: no-cache
postman-token: db0faf20-d49c-485a-8712-4d31bc65615a
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.1.5
accept: */*
host: localhost:8081
cookie: JSESSIONID=AC9D0F63FB67F51917751325403CC4B1
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 505
connection: keep-alive


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:65 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of     request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token' 2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:68 - matched
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /oauth/token at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /oauth/token at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /oauth/token at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:130 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@42b51d34
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /oauth/token at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:65 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:137 - Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'GET /logout
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:65 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/logout'
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:65 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:137 - Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:65 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:137 - Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:72 - No matches found
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /oauth/token at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG BasicAuthenticationFilter:170 - Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'client'
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG ProviderManager:169 - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG DaoAuthenticationProvider:87 - Authentication failed: password does not match stored value
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG BasicAuthenticationFilter:198 - Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint:78 - Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint:91 - No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@68e001ed
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:119 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

And the response is 401 Unathorized:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 - Error report</title>
    <style>
        <!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}-->
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 401 - Unauthorized</h1>
    <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
    <p>
        <b>type</b> Status report
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>message</b>
        <u>Unauthorized</u>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>description</b>
        <u>This request requires HTTP authentication.</u>
    </p>
    <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
    <h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.47</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: can you go into a bit more detail on what OAuth2 solves for you that Basic authentication does not? I know that you are under pressure to get something working, but I'll need to understand your use case better to make a recommendation.

Comment: Also, just a bit of cleanup. you have two secrets configured in your client configuration. You are calling `.secret` twice. It appears that the app would think, based on your configuration, that client/secret is a valid u/p combo, but your curl is using client/clientpassword in the Authorization header.

Comment: And, to make testing this easier, I'd recommend the following curl command instead: `curl client:secret@localhost:8081/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=user -d password=user` This way you don't have to worry about encoding the client id and secret yourself and you have no raw headers to post.

Comment: @jzheaux Thank you for helping me out. So we have a single page Javascript app with a backend using Java Spring 5 API. It has been working fine. Now another team inside our company also want to access the same Spring 5 API that we are using. We are trying to figure out a way so that they can access it.

Comment: @jzheaux The other team has been accessing some other unrelated projects using a token-like system (not Spring). They would like to access our API similarly with a token. So this may be similar to Oauth2 password grant. From what I have read, their app is trusted by us. And their app is connecting to our API using backend, so nothing will be exposed to any user.

Comment: Thanks, @sliks, that's helpful.

Comment: While you are getting this password grant to work, remember that the password grant is really intended for testing and that the client_credentials grant would probably be a better fit if you don't require user consent.

So, your logs show that the client login is failing. Because the client login is failing, I'd focus on whether your username and password are correct. Maybe first start with getting the sample in the Spring docs working first and then compare.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-authorization-server

Comment: Also, just one more thing. The reason your curl doesn't have an error is because it is missing the `-v` parameter. Try taking the curl command I recommended and adding a `-v` to it.

Comment: @jzheaux Thank you for your help. The link you sent was very helpful. I finally got a token out from our system. I removed the extra .secret() and use a the client password without encoding. 

And this is my request:
curl client:secret@localhost:8081/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=user -d password=user

Now I will need to move forward and make it according to our requirement, maybe change it to client_credentials grant. Thank you for your help.

Comment: glad it's working for you now. I took our discussion and posted a cleaned-up version as the answer to the question in case other folks have the same issue in the future and stumble on the question. Feel free to mark it as the correct answer, or let me know if it needs to be adjusted to be more helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the code is calling `.secret` twice in the client service setup:

```
clients.inMemory().withClient("client")
    .secret("clientpassword")
    .secret("{noop}secret")
    ...
```

And the logs are complaining about the `client` having Bad Credentials:

```
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG BasicAuthenticationFilter:170 - Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'client'
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG ProviderManager:169 - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG DaoAuthenticationProvider:87 - Authentication failed: password does not match stored value
2018-09-05 22:42:36 DEBUG BasicAuthenticationFilter:198 - Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
```

If I [base64-decode](https://codebeautify.org/base64-decode) the `Authorization` header from your sample request, the password you are using is `clientpassword`, which will work if you instead do:

```
clients.inMemory().withClient("client")
    .secret("{noop}clientpassword")
    // .secret("{noop}secret") 
    // omit the other .secret call and continue w/ remaining config
    ...
```

Also, when you are ready to move on from exploration mode, remember to extract that password at least into a properties file and encode it, e.g. `{bcrypt}$2y$12$8UyEwJ1iwyGqXrxfmH...`

Lastly, probably some of the confusion could be simplified by using a simpler curl call that leaves the password in plaintext. Likely:

`curl -v client:clientpassword@localhost:8081/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=user -d password=user`

Will keep everything simple and in front of you.

Comment: You are awesome. We make it work with your help. Really appreciate! Thank you so much!